# How to verify using Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

```
Class Sample{

 int property1;
 int property2;


protected method1(Object1 obj1)
{
  .
  .
  obj1.process(new Object2(property1,property2));
  .
  .
}

}
```

I want to verify that obj1.process is called with certain value. Im happy to provide more clarification.

Comment: Mockito comes with great documentation. Why don't you read that and start trying? You don't learn when you try to get other people to do your work.

Comment: Not to mention there are countless examples of this on this site and all over the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a mocked object to the method, something like this:

```
Sample objectToTest = new Sample();

Object1 mockedObject1 = mock(Object1.class);
objectToTest.process(mockedObject1);

Object2 obj2 = new Object2(expectedValue1, expectedValue1);
verify(mockedObject1).process(obj2);
```

Make sure that Object2 implements equals.